# how to iterate over projects, datasets in BigQuery using a SQL query

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

assume i have a list of projects in BigQuery and each project has several datasets. i'd like to extract data from all these tables into one table only using SQL:

this query below works on one project (yay!) but how can i iterate it through several projects?

```
DECLARE schema_list ARRAY<STRING>;
DECLARE iter INT64 DEFAULT 0;

SET schema_list = (
 SELECT
   ARRAY_AGG(schema_name)
 FROM
   $project.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
 );

WHILE
  iter < ARRAY_LENGTH(schema_list) DO
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE format(""" 
    INSERT `$other_project.$data_set.$table` (col1, col2, something) 
    SELECT  
      col1,
      col2,
      (really clever calc) as something
    FROM `$project.%s.198401*`
    GROUP BY
      col1,
      col2,
    """, schema_list[OFFSET(iter)]);
    
    SET iter = iter + 1;
END WHILE;
```

i don't mind suppling the projects via an array but if the query could get the list of projects itself it would be a blast!

thanks a million!
even just for trying :)

Answer (score 1):

An approach I can think of might require you to write code (Python, Nodejs, Java, etc) to use BigQuery API. This approach will loop through a list of projects and execute your query per iteration.

1. Use [BQ endpoint projects.list](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects/list) to get a list of projects to which the user has been granted any project role. Or use [Resource Manager API](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/) if necessary.
2. When you have the list of projects, loop through the list of projects, pass the `project_id` to your query (modify your query to accept query parameters).
3. Use [query parameters](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries) to safely pass your `project_id` to your query to prevent SQL injection.
4. Execute your query that you have posted on your question using BQ API. See [querying using a programming language](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-queries).

Comment: the only issue i still found in the script above is that if the dataset doesn't consist of the table with the prefix i'm searching for it will fail. i tried using the bq IF but it can't be used in an "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE". so i end up just using the script to do all the looping. bq sql has it's limitations when looping via different datasets and different . shame